# How do I disable foreground views to do fling on background

Tags: java, android, touch

I have LinearLayout that has 1) Views on it and 2) has a Gesture detector. My problem is that when I want to do a fling gesture on the linear layout, if my finger comes across any of the views, it will throw a MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL which will prevent the onFling() callback firing.

I can't really disable touch on those foreground views because they are part of a navigation to launch Intents.

Thx,
-mL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to take a look inside of ViewPager how it does.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

You need to create your LinearLayout (by simply extending Android's LinearLayout) and override onInterceptTouchEvent. This is called before child and if it returns true parent steals touch from children.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: I was able to leverage onInterceptTouchEvent(). Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound as if you have the GestureOverlayView as the root element in your layout perhaps?

Short example:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

See here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

Comment: Thx Pulsar, I am not using GestureOverlayView. Looks a lot more involved that I would have to bring in Gesture Libraries and it's Predictions when all I want is a fling which is defined here in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html. The GestureOverlayView version is much more complicated.